# Building PoDoFo on Windows - unresolved externals

Tags: c++, linker-errors, unresolved-external, podofo

I'm trying to build [PoDoFo](http://sourceforge.net/projects/podofo/) but I have few linker errors that are related to OpenSSL(I think). I tried to build it(OpenSSL) but it was too complicated, so I downloaded Win64 OpenSSL v1.0.1e from http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.

I made Visual Studio solution from this code:

```
del cmakecache.txt
set FTDIR=D:\Iwan\Projekty\PDF_projekt\freetype-2.4.11
set FTLIBDIR=D:\Iwan\Projekty\PDF_projekt\freetype-2.4.11\objs\win32\vc2010
set JPEGDIR=D:\Iwan\Projekty\PDF_projekt\jpeg-9
set ZLIBDIR=D:\Iwan\Projekty\PDF_projekt\zlib127-dll
set LIBCRYPTODIR=C:\OpenSSL-Win64
cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" ..\podofo-0.9.2 -DCMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH="%FTDIR%\include;%JPEGDIR%\include;%JPEGDIR%;%ZLIBDIR%\include;%LIBCRYPTODIR%\include;%LIBCRYPTODIR%\include\openssl" -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH="%FTLIBDIR%;%FTDIR%\lib;%JPEGDIR%\lib;%JPEGDIR%;%ZLIBDIR%\lib;%LIBCRYPTODIR%\lib\VC" -DPODOFO_BUILD_SHARED:BOOL=TRUE -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG=freetype2411MT_D -DFREETYPE_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE=freetype2411MT -DLIBCRYPTO_LIBRARY_NAMES_DEBUG=libeay32MDd -DLIBCRYPTO_LIBRARY_NAMES_RELEASE=libeay32MD
```

I'm not sure what library should I add in options, but I tried libeay32MD, sleay32MD, libeay32MT, ssleay32MT, libeay32 and ssleay32.

When I tried compiling created solution I got these linker errors:

```
2>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
2>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMT' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_init referenced in function "public: __thiscall PoDoFo::AESCryptoEngine::AESCryptoEngine(void)" (??0AESCryptoEngine@PoDoFo@@QAE@XZ)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup referenced in function "public: __thiscall PoDoFo::AESCryptoEngine::~AESCryptoEngine(void)" (??1AESCryptoEngine@PoDoFo@@QAE@XZ)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptFinal_ex referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall PoDoFo::PdfEncryptRC4Base::RC4(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *,int)" (?RC4@PdfEncryptRC4Base@PoDoFo@@IAEXPBEH0HPAEH@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptUpdate referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall PoDoFo::PdfEncryptRC4Base::RC4(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *,int)" (?RC4@PdfEncryptRC4Base@PoDoFo@@IAEXPBEH0HPAEH@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_key_length referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall PoDoFo::PdfEncryptRC4Base::RC4(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *,int)" (?RC4@PdfEncryptRC4Base@PoDoFo@@IAEXPBEH0HPAEH@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_EncryptInit_ex referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall PoDoFo::PdfEncryptRC4Base::RC4(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *,int)" (?RC4@PdfEncryptRC4Base@PoDoFo@@IAEXPBEH0HPAEH@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_rc4 referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall PoDoFo::PdfEncryptRC4Base::RC4(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *,int)" (?RC4@PdfEncryptRC4Base@PoDoFo@@IAEXPBEH0HPAEH@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Final referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl PoDoFo::PdfEncryptMD5Base::GetMD5Binary(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *)" (?GetMD5Binary@PdfEncryptMD5Base@PoDoFo@@SAXPBEHPAE@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Update referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl PoDoFo::PdfEncryptMD5Base::GetMD5Binary(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *)" (?GetMD5Binary@PdfEncryptMD5Base@PoDoFo@@SAXPBEHPAE@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MD5_Init referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl PoDoFo::PdfEncryptMD5Base::GetMD5Binary(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *)" (?GetMD5Binary@PdfEncryptMD5Base@PoDoFo@@SAXPBEHPAE@Z)
2>PdfEncrypt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_aes_128_cbc referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall PoDoFo::PdfEncryptAESBase::AES(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char *,int)" (?AES@PdfEncryptAESBase@PoDoFo@@IAEXPBEH00HPAEH@Z)
```

I'm trying to do compile this for 2 days, but nothing I do works, and I can't find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the OpenSSL yourself. It is not that complicated - here is the relevant list of commands, taken from install.w64 file bundled with the source code:

```
 > perl Configure VC-WIN64A
 > ms\do_win64a
 > nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak
 > cd out32dll
 > ..\ms\test
```

What is not mentioned here you should run it from within visual studio's command prompt (Tools menu). Perl will not be visible there, so you should run a command first:

```
set path=%path;c:\perl\bin
```